# PHPUnit_Framework_Exception when trying to run Codeception / Selenium with Internet Explorer 11 / IE11

Tags: selenium, phpunit, internet-explorer-11, codeception

When I try to run my Codeception tests with Internet Explorer 11, I get the following error:

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by re-starting Selenium with a passthru flag.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -enablePassThrough false
```