# WebDriverException throws when using Codeception / Selenium with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11, codeception

When I try to run Codeception / Selenium with Internet Explorer 11, I get the following error message.

In WebDriverException.php line 134:

> Unable to get browser
>   Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time:
>   '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'   System info: host: 'JEREMYPIVENSGHOST', ip:
>   '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.   version: '1.8.0_141'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit\_Framework\_Exception when trying to run Codeception / Selenium with Internet Explorer 11 / IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799845/phpunit-framework-exception-when-trying-to-run-codeception-selenium-with-inter)

Comment: It's not. Two seperate issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by following these steps:

- Open up Internet Explorer 11
- Press the Alt key to bring up the IE11 menu bar.
- Select Tools > Internet Options and go to the Security tab.
- Select each zone (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) and check the Enable Protected Mode check box.

Credits to Michael Whelan for this answer:
http://www.michael-whelan.net/selenium-webdriver-and-ie11/